# Change Row background color with new DataTables API

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have started using the new DataTables API v1.10.2 and would like to know how I can optimize this bit of my code.

At first, for me to hide a column, I used this code:

```
"aoColumnDefs": [
            {
            "targets": [ 0 ],
            "visible": false,
            "searchable": false
            },
            {
            "targets": [ 4 ],
            "visible": false
            },
```

Now I used this which makes the code smaller and easy to understand:

```
"columns": [
        { "data": "source", "visible": false },
        ........
        { "data": "host" }
```

What I would like is to see how I can optimize another code that checks for a value (1-5) in a column using **fnRowCallback** and changes the row color if it meets the condition using the new DataTables 1.10.2:

Code:

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
    if ( aData.priority == "5" )
    {
        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Red');
        red++;
    }
    else if ( aData.priority == "4" )
    {
        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');
        orange++;
    }
    {
    ..........
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess the only best option I had was this:

"rowCallback": function ( row, data ) {
     if ( data.priority == "5" ){ $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');}
     else if ( data.priority == "4" ){ $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Orange');}

Answer (score 4):

I guess the only best option I had was this:

```
"rowCallback": function ( row, data ) { 
   if ( data.priority == "5" ){ $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Red');}
   else if ( data.priority == "4" ){ $('td', row).css('background-color', 'Orange');}
}
```